# Specifying which point buffers fall within a particualar land type (polygon)

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, interpolation, spatial-statistics, climate

I have a point buffer layer which represents tick occurrence and a polygon layer which represents landcover types (derived from Corine land cover). I want to define which point buffers (1km) fall within urban areas to define risk zones. I also want to do this for thresholds of temperature and precipitation (which presumably I'm going to interpolate as gridded and mask onto polygon) to define 'high-risk zones'. I’m quite NEW to QGIS so not sure how to approach this. I have tried using the intersect tool but that just selects all the points from the land cover layer.

[image]

Attribute table for points

[image]
Attribute table for land cover

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select by attribute` all urban areas from the landcover layer and export them to a new layer. Then `select by position` all buffers which intersect with the newly exported layer. Export the selected features to a new layer.

Comment: Thanks, can I do that for multiple 'urban' classes using an expression?

Comment: Sure you can. Ideally use something like `"column-name" in ('class1','class2',etc)`. Though CORINE has got a superclass for all urban areas, hasn't it?

Comment: Yes it's called 'continuous urban fabric' but I'm combining other classes which relate to infrastructure (e.g.discontinous urban fabric) to make it less noisy by colour coding as I don't know how to merge the ID codes in the attribute table together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Add Polygon Attributes to points tool under SAGA which will transfer the land cover field from the polygon attribute table to the points attribute table.

The tool is located under `Processing toolbox -> SAGA -> Vector Points tools -> Add Polygon Attributes to points`:

[image]

Make sure that both vector files have the same CRS.

Another option is to use Join Attribute by location tool and use Intersects as geometric predicates:

[image]